# Why do SVGs (size, positioning) differ in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, svg

When I display an SVG (created by d3.js) in Chrome, it has different dimensions as in Firefox or in IE.

E.g. Let's take this code:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3885304/

Firefox: The g element is 923 x 473.1
[image]

Chrome: The g element is 921 x 468.094
[image]

How do I change the Javascript/CSS/HTML to make this graph have the same position in Chrome, firefox, IE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect it is to do with differences in the fonts and how they are being rendered.  You are only specifying "10px sans-serif".  Even if the same font is being used by both browsers, it would not be inconcievable that differences in how the browser measures and renders each piece of text may result in a few pixels of variance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! And how do I specify the fonts to be the same ?